# Why nodejs is behaving very strange with my code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ajax, api

I don't know why but I got confused regarding Nodejs one behaviour.

**Following is my nodejs code** `my server is running at port:8080`

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const multer = require("multer");
const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors({
    origin:"http://localhost:4000"
}))
app.get("/userinfo", async (req, res) => {
    console.log("reached heree");
  res.json({
    message: "access",
  });
});
app.listen(
  8080,
  (error) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log("error");
    }
  },
  () => {
    console.log("listening at port 8080");
  }
);
```

And I am trying to hit API from a different origin [localhost:3000]

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import axios from "axios";
function App() {
  const makeRequest =()=>{
     axios.get("http://localhost:8080/userinfo").then(response=>{
       console.log(response);
     }).catch((e)=>{
       console.log(e);
     })
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={makeRequest}>Click</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

But when I click `Click` when I inspect the code, I got an error message as expected `You are blocked by CORS policy`.But when I see in terminal on my server-side, I see output `Reached here`.
At this point, I got too confused and frustrated at the same time. How cross-site request triggered `/userinfo` from the different origin?. I don't think this should happen.
How can I solve this issue??

Comment: Why do you have this code `app.use(cors({ origin:"http://localhost:4000"}))` if your client is running on 3000 port?

Comment: Yes, I am blocked by CORS policy but why "/userinfo" got executed on server despite of being blocked by CORS.

Comment: because CORS blocks client from **reading the response** - it does not block a client from **making a request**. because there's such a concept as "opaque response" - i.e. a CORS request where the client doesn't need to access the response

Comment: Sinan Yaman : I added that code to  simulate `localhost:3000` is not allowed to communicate with my server running at port 8080.  But despite of being blocked by CORS why my "/userinfo" first line got executed

Comment: @SundarGautam read above comment - CORS does not do what you think it does :p

Comment: @Bravo Thank you for your words :-) But can i ask you another question? How can I prevent client not to reach inside "/userinfo" from cors?

Comment: I just explained that this has nothing to do with CORS - you'll need some other methods to determine where the request comes from - which can be easily spoofed anyway - i.e. not easy, but still nothing to do with CORS

Comment: @SundarGautam That Response is blocked by the browser, as according to your CORS policy, localhost:4000 will be sent as allowed origin in response header of your request as it doesn't match the origin browser will block the request

Comment: @Sumanth Madishetty Yes,I am also telling that both are different origin so I got blocked.My Question was if this is the condition then why my code at server got executed. But I got my answer from @Bravo. You can read above answer :-) `because CORS blocks client from reading the response - it does not block a client from making a request. because there's such a concept as "opaque response" - i.e. a CORS request where the client doesn't need to access the response `

Answer (score 1):

It's not your server that is blocking the request. Your server SHOULD send back the HTTP request because servers and WIFI and your router does not care about CORS.

It is the web browser that blocks the CORS. Blocking CORS does not mean you don't hit the server endpoint. It does not even mean that the HTTP packet is blocked. Blocking CORS means **your web browser is refusing to let your javascript code from reading the data returned by the server**.

The purpose of CORS is to bypass the original Same-origin policy which is still enforced today. The same-origin policy was added when javascript was added to web browsers. It allows web browsers to make HTTP requests but tries to prevent malicious scripts from listening in to HTTP data by disallowing scripts to read the result of HTTP requests (`XMLHttpRequest` or `fetch`) unless the URL is from the same domain as the page.

The **only** thing CORS adds is a header that your server can send back to the browser that tells the browser that it's OK for javascript code to access the result of the HTTP request.